# Correction to try/finally

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

I'm trying to close my resultset, connection and statement with a try/finally but Sonar doesn't seem to like it. What mistake am I doing and why aren't they closing? Thanks.

```
public static List<String> findByName(String firstName, String lastName) throws SQLException {

    /*Connects  to  table and contexts a statement to this connection. Creates the appropriate statement (query)
    according to the first name and last name nulls, builds an array from the ResultSet that is created.*/
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList();
    String query;

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement preparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet allNames = null;

    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getHost(), getuName(), getuPass());
        preparedStatement = conn.createStatement();
        if (firstName == null && lastName == null) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c";
        } else if (firstName == null) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c WHERE LAST_NAME= '" + lastName + "'";
        } else if (lastName == null) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c where FIRST_NAME= '" + firstName + "'";
        } else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c where FIRST_NAME =  '" + firstName + "'" + "AND LAST_NAME= '" + lastName + "'";
        }
        allNames = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
        while (allNames.next()) {
            nameList.add(allNames.getString("FIRST_NAME") + "  " + allNames.getString("LAST_NAME"));
        }
    } finally {
        if (allNames != null) allNames.close();
        if (preparedStatement!=null)  preparedStatement.close();
        if (conn!=null) conn.close();
    }
    return nameList;
}
```

Comment: *doesn't seem to like it.* - That is not very technical is it?  What is the error?

Comment: from the security aspect i would say this sql query is vulnerable to sql injection. Dont use `"SELECT * FROM person_c WHERE LAST_NAME= '" + lastName + "'";`. Use parameterized statements instead. [More Information to SQL Injections](https://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement)

Comment: Thank  you MapReduce - something I will  keep in mind in future. At the moment we're just doing exercises as I'm an apprentice. I've completed the code but tidying up the edges.

Comment: @MapReduce - OMG, how did I miss the fact there was string concat in those queries?!

Answer (score 3):

There are three unrelated problems in that code:

1. In theory, `close` can throw. If any of your previous `close` calls throws, later ones won't be done. Also, if an exception is already underway, an exception from those `close` calls will override it, hiding the true problem. The solution is to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
2. You're calling `executeQuery(String)` on a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Never do that, it's treating `PreparedStatement` as though it were just a `Statement`. (It's an API design mistake.) Pass the query into `prepareStatement` instead.
3. Don't use string concatenation to put values into a query. That's the point of `PreparedStatement`: To parameterize the query safely. (Let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com/)...)

So handling all three of those:

```
public static List<String> findByName(String firstName, String lastName) throws SQLException {

    /*Connects  to  table and contexts a statement to this connection. Creates the appropriate statement (query)
    according to the first name and last name nulls, builds an array from the ResultSet that is created.*/
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList();
    String query;

    try (
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getHost(), getuName(), getuPass());
    ) {
        if (firstName == null && lastName == null) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c";
        } else if (firstName == null) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c WHERE LAST_NAME = ?";
        } else if (lastName == null) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c where FIRST_NAME = ?";
        } else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM person_c where FIRST_NAME = ? AND LAST_NAME = ?";
        }
        try (
            Statement preparedStatement = conn.createStatement(query);
        ) {
            int n = 1;
            if (firstName != null) {
                preparedStatement.setString(n++, firstName);
            }
            if (lastName != null) {
                preparedStatement.setString(n++, lastName);
            }
            try (
                ResultSet allNames = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            ) {
                while (allNames.next()) {
                    nameList.add(allNames.getString("FIRST_NAME") + "  " + allNames.getString("LAST_NAME"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nameList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Crowder - you've been very helpful. Will give it a go :-)

Comment: @HywelGriffiths - No worries. I'm afraid I missed the string concatenation in your code earlier, and I also forgot to remove `query` from `executeQuery` in my updated example Both fixed now, sorry about that.